# Inverse gauge transformation in general relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Can someone explain to me how (8.21) follows from (8.20). 
The Picture comes from A first course in general relativity (Schutz).
Thanks and regards,
Jens Wagemaker
[image]

Comment: Hint: The second thing is supposed to be the inverse, but only to *first order* in $\xi$: Check whether this holds or not!

Comment: @Danu I have checked what u have said, and indeed the second thing is the inverse if seconds order terms are neglected, thanks!

Comment: This question is solved, but I don't know were to mark it solved.

Comment: There is no such mark without an answer posted.

Comment: Should I then delete the post?

Comment: I do not normally advocate deleting posts, it is entirely your choice.

Comment: I have posted an answer myself, which I can accept in 2 days, so that would seal the deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(8.21) is the inverse of (8.20) up to **first order**.